# Git: renamed file causes conflicts when compiling in java

Tags: java, git

A long time ago, I created a repository and commited a file called CameraAction.java.

As time went by, I discovered the capitalization of the 'A' was causing some problems with Spring Boot (can't remember exactly what the problem was), but decided it would be safer to call my class Cameraaction.java instead.

Now, each time I pull from git, I get the CameraAction.java file name instead of Cameraaction.java.

This causes a conflict when I compile the app as the filename and the class name are not spelt the same:

```
CameraAction.java:12: error: class Cameraaction is public, should be declared in a file named Cameraaction.java
        public class Cameraaction extends Action {
               ^
```

How do I solve this?

I tried to do this:

```
git rm --cached CameraAction.java
```

but it just comes back to me saying:

```
fatal: pathspec 'CameraAction.java' did not match any files
```

Comment: You'd better keep it named CameraAction.java, and rename your class: that's the standard Java naming convention, and Spring has no problem with that.

Comment: I actually did change the name - refactored them now, and it worked. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To commit `CameraAction.java` as `Cameraaction.java` (not that it is the right thing to do, see link on Java naming conventions below) try doing the following:

```
git mv -f CameraAction.java Cameraaction.java
```

followed by a `git commit -m "Fixed the case of a file"` and a `git push`
Confirm that the problem is gone by doing a fresh `git clone` and checking that the file is checked out as `Cameraaction.java`

If while doing the above, you get a 'File Exists' error, then use a tmp file to do it, like so:

```
git mv CameraAction.java CameraAction.java.tmp
git mv CameraAction.java.tmp Cameraaction.java
```

But as noted by a commenter above, the [Java Naming Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) do have the following to say about class names:

[image]

---

#### How does git handle case-insensitive file systems?

Git has a configuration setting that tells it whether to be case sensitive or insensitive: `core.ignorecase`. To tell Git to be case-senstive, simply set this setting to `false`:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

From the [`git config` documentation](http://jk.gs/git-config.html):

> `core.ignorecase`
>
> If true, this option enables various workarounds to enable git to work better on filesystems that are not case sensitive, like FAT. For example, if a directory listing finds `makefile` when git expects `Makefile`, git will assume it is really the same file, and continue to remember it as `Makefile`.
>
> The default is false, except [git-clone(1)](http://jk.gs/git-clone.html) or [git-init(1)](http://jk.gs/git-init.html) will probe and set `core.ignorecase` true if appropriate when the repository is created.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you on? Most likely you are not on a *nix. Specifically, you probably have a case preserving, but case non-sensitive filesystem.

You could try renaming the file yourself to `Cameraaction.java`, or just `rm CameraAction; git checkout -- Cameraaction.java`.